# Xcode5-ios7 Linphone not running with lastest changes incorporated (i.e code) on Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios7, osx-mountain-lion, xcode5, linphone

I'm having an issue with linphone (ios7) and Xcode 5. Here is what is happening, When I run the linphone app on the ios simultor, I am able to see the latest changes incorporated for example code. When I run the same linphone app on my Iphone (since  I have a developper licence), I am not able to see any change made in the code as I can see when I run on the simulator. 
It seems like linphone is running with its first version. I tried clean xcode cache (Product > Clean) but it doesnt change anything. I also delete this folder

```
/Users/%yourusername%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/%yourworkplacename%/.
```

What's going on here? Is there a simple setting that I am missing? Can you please help me ?

Thank you

Best regards

Comment: delete the app that you have downloaded from app store as well and try again !

Comment: @Maulik  Thank you for your answer.Did you face the same issue in the past?

Comment: yes... and I solved it by deleting the app